# How can I use react-native-bottom-sheet on a map, when happens when a marker is pressed?

Tags: reactjs

I was able to make this without the map. Here's a pic

[image: 1]

using this code:

```
const App = () => {
  const [animationValue, setAnimationValue] = useState(-1000)
  const showAnimation = useRef(new Animated.Value(animationValue)).current


  const toggleAnimation = () => {
    const val = animationValue === 0 ? -1000 : 0
    Animated.timing(showAnimation, {
      useNativeDriver: false,
      toValue: val,
      duration: 350
    }).start()
    setAnimationValue(val)
  }
  return (
    <>
      <View
        onTouchStart={() => {
          if (animationValue === 0) {
            toggleAnimation()
          }
        }}
        style={{ flex: 1, zIndex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <Button title="Marker" onPress={() => {
          toggleAnimation()
        }} />
      </View>
      <BottomSheet onCancel={() => {
        toggleAnimation()
      }} animation={showAnimation} />

    </>

  )
}
```

But I want to use this code on a map, when the maker is pressed I want the bottomsheet to pop up? Here's my map code

```
<View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView
          provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
          style={styles.map}
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: 34.052235,
            longitude: -118.243683,
            latitudeDelta: 0.01,
            longitudeDelta: 0.09,
          }}>
          <Marker
            coordinate={{ latitude: 34.052235, longitude: -118.243683 }}>
            <Callout>
              <Text>Marker</Text>
            </Callout>
          </Marker>
        </MapView>
      </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am doing this with [react-native-bottom-sheet](https://github.com/gorhom/react-native-bottom-sheet) using useEffect to open/close it (if you're willing to change libraries). This has been working well with RN maps.

```js
  const bottomSheetModalRef = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (markerModalOpen) {
      bottomSheetModalRef.current?.present()
    } else {
      bottomSheetModalRef.current?.dismiss()
    }
  }, [markerModalOpen])

 return (
    <BottomSheetModalProvider>
      <BottomSheetModal
        ref={bottomSheetModalRef}
        index={0}
        snapPoints={snapPoints}
        onDismiss={() => dispatch(closeModal())}
        backgroundStyle={{ backgroundColor: "#25292E", flex: 1 }}
      >
        ....
        ....
      </BottomSheetModal>
    </BottomSheetModalProvider>
  )
```